# SQL error 'column "zona" is of type box but expression is of type record'

Tags: sql, postgresql, record

I'm kind of new to SQL, I have seen similar question to this one, however I was not able to fix my problem just by looking at those solutions.
(working on postgres)

I have a table anomalia:

```
create table anomalia(
  id integer,
  zona box not null,
  imagem varchar(50) not null,
  lingua char(3) not null,
  ts timestamp not null,
  descricao text not null,
  tem_anomalia_redacao boolean not null,
  primary key(id)
);
```

and when I try to:

```
insert into anomalia values (22, ((2, 4), (8, 9)), 'imagem2.png', 'por', '2003-09-21 22:54:56', 'Texto muito pequeno', TRUE);
```

I get this error:

```
psql:schema.sql:129: ERROR:  column "zona" is of type box but expression is of type record                           
LINE 1: insert into anomalia values (22, ((2, 4), (8, 9)), 'imagem2....
```

From what I've read, the problem most likely has to do with parentheses, but I can't figure it out. Would thank you if you tried to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply surround the values of the zona field in single quotes as in:

```
insert into anomalia values (22, '((2, 4), (8, 9))', 'imagem2.png', 'por', '2003-09-21 22:54:56', 'Texto muito pequeno', TRUE);
```